# D3 select all nodes with same data content

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got a bunch of nodes with an additional attribute "type". I want to highlight all nodes from type server as soon as a server node is selected. Which works fine because its hard coded.

But how can I realize it dynamically, for different "types" for example client or software. The code should recognize the type of node. I tested to replace the filters with "this" but it also wasn´t working.

```
node
    .filter((d) => {
        return d.type == "server"
    })
    .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
        node.filter((d) => {
            return d.type == "server"
        }).style("fill", "lightblue")
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
        node.filter((d) => {
            return d.type == "server"
        }).style("fill", "whitesmoke")
    } )
```

Comment: Doesn't filter after node already filters out all other types that are not of server type? Then you just need to set the style in mouse functions (without filtering). Or you can define a new nodeFiltered variable and add mouse functions to it etc.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. When the user mouses over a node with type of "server", you want to change the fill color of all nodes with type "server"?  Something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/8WhGPlYRV4AQqxRh?preview).

Comment: The leading type is available in your `d` already. Use different parameter names to avoid shadowing and something like `.on("mouseenter", d => node.filter(n => n.type === d.type).style("fill", "lightblue"))` should do the trick.

Comment: @MattSergejRinc yes and no, if you do not add another filter than only the current hovered node of type "server" changes the colour.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your input, you did it the same way like I. Hard coded, but I need it dynamical as I got a bunch of types. https://jsfiddle.net/7pabyhzm/ The code should recognize the hovered node, get the type and search for all nodes with the same type. Afterwards change the colour of all. For example the black nodes are from type "client" they should also change the colour if you hover over.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks four your help. Unfortunately it doesn´t or I made a mistake. Looks like I need to store the name / type of the hovered node first. Afterwards I could use it to compare those value with the function. https://jsfiddle.net/7pabyhzm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done. Need to select the d.name or whatever you want to filter. Afterwards you can use the filter function and compare the values.

```
<script>
  var selection

  let data = d3.range(10)
    .map(function(d){
      return {
        name: Math.random() > 0.5 ? "server" : "client",
        x: Math.random() * 480,
        y: Math.random() * 480
      };
    });

  var nodes = d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .on("mouseenter", function(d){
        selection = d.name
        console.log("Enter " + d.name + " " + selection)
        nodes.filter ( (n) => {
            return n.name === d.name
        })
        .attr("fill", "blue")
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function(d){
        selection = d.name
        console.log("Exit " + d.name + " " + selection)
        nodes.filter( (n) => {
            return n.name === d.name
        })
        .attr("fill", "black")
    })
</script>
```